# Cannot find Home link in Pages on Dashboard

Tags: menus

I cannot see the Home page link in the WordPress menus section. Here's how the Pages box look like this:

[image: screenshot]

How can I get the link of Home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom link and drag it to the menu:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for the default Home link, because the theme has defined some specific style for that link and if I add custom home link, it does not get applied. Do you have any idea why it disappeared and how can I get it back? Thank again.

Comment: @jay Is it actually a real page?

Comment: No, just the link to homepage. Usually I see this link in the 'View All' tabs (http://i.imgur.com/35tKvol.png), but in one installation I cannot see tabs or that home link. Isn't it available by default?

Comment: No, by default, there is no link for the home page. make sure the URL in the URL field is the same as your real front page.